# How can I add an info bubble to a mapxtreme map in asp net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, mapinfo, mapxtreme

I'm using MapXtreme 2008 v7 for a learning project, and was wondering is there any way to make a bubble appear with data when you pass a mouse over a point?.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to understand how mapxtreme works:
For **MapXtreme Web**,I can say there is only one image in given size.Since there is one you must add with javascript,but there will be lots of asynchronous posting which will make your application slow.
Unfortunately there is no standard for user interaction as mouseover,you need to write your own logic,but this logic wont be so sensible,because you can always mouse over by doing another interaction,like drawing rectangle,make selections etc.

Best way of doing it is using **Tiling**.Tiling feature has arrived with MapXtreme v7.Logic you will use is putting your map into [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) etc.OpenLayers support whole chart of tiling including your maps.There is an example for Tiling in CodeExchange as MXTTileHandler.zip.
You can download it from [here](http://www.pbinsight.com/communities/code-exchange/).

What you can do:
1)Publish your map as WMS and put it into OpenLayers
2)Release your map as Tile and put it into OpenLayers

Best Regards 
Myra